Exclude rel="amphtml" tag from Specific NextJS Page
I have created my website using NextJS. I want to remove rel="amphtml" tag for a particular page(on the basis of URL).
Like I want to exclude rel="amphtml" tag from sports category non amp Articles, while remaining category Articles remain intact.
I have tried the given code for this.
{
isAmp ? '' : <link rel="amphtml" href={`${DomainName}${asPathURL}lite/`} /> 
}


For this you can use router.query, through which you can detect category and applied condition accordingly. As you mentioned you want to remove rel="amphtml" tag from sports category. You can do this by using given code.
{
isAmp || 'sports' === router.query.slug ? '' : <link rel="amphtml" href={`${DomainName}${asPathURL}lite/`} /> 
}


Please try this solution to help us with this code
import Head from "next/head";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useAmp } from 'next/amp';

export const config = { amp: 'hybrid' };

const SeoMeta = () => {
    let router = useRouter();
    let asPath = router.asPath;
    let asPathURL = asPath.split('?')[0];
    const isAmp = useAmp();

    let DomainName = 'https://www.google.com'

    return (
        <Head>
            {
            typePost === 'sports'
            ? <>
                {
                    isAmp ? '' : 
                    <link rel="amphtml" href={`${DomainName}${asPathURL}lite/`} />
                }
             </>
            : ''
            }
        </Head>
    );
};

export default SeoMeta;

